# Flutter:get document id form firstore when setData is called

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

How to get the newly created document id when we call setData

```
 Future<void> createCommitment() async {
        await widget._firestore
           .collection('skills')
           .document(widget.skillID)
           .collection("commitment")
           .document()
           .setData({
         'bite_id': widget.biteId,
         'start_date': widget.startDate,
         'frequnecy': 3
       });
     }
```

the current implementation returns void

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to either set it yourself:

```
DocumentReference _skillsRef = Firestore.instance.collection('skills').document(skillsID);
```

or auto-generate it:

```
DocumentReference _skillsRef = Firestore.instance.collection('skills').document();
```

and that ref is what you set it on:

```
_skillsRef.setData({
    'bite_id': widget.biteId,
    'start_date': widget.startDate,
    'frequency': 3
})
```

Answer (score 5):

Don't use an empty `document()` or `setData`,  instead `seData` use `add` like this :

```
Future<void> createCommitment() async {
  DocumentReference docRef = await widget._firestore
      .collection('skills')
      .document(widget.skillID)
      .collection("commitment")
      .add({
    'bite_id': widget.biteId,
    'start_date': widget.startDate,
    'frequnecy': 3,
  });
  //Here you have the autogenerated ID :
  print("ID : ${docRef.documentID}");
}
```